# Is it possible to connect EV3 and NXT bricks like master/slave configuration via bluetooth?

Tags: mindstorms, nxt, ev3, bluetooth

Can I make a Bluetooth connection between LEGO EV3 bricks and LEGO NXT bricks? and If it is possible how to handle the software to make  a chain between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possible ways of doing this. I am a contributor to the [ev3dev](http://www.ev3dev.org) project, so I am a bit biased in that direction.

To do this with ev3dev, I would install the [nxt-python](https://code.google.com/p/nxt-python/) package on the EV3 and use it to remote control the NXT.

If you want to stick with the standard firmware, another possibility would be to relay bluetooth mailbox messages through a PC or other device. [Here](http://siouxnetontrack.wordpress.com/2013/10/08/using-the-nxt-as-an-ev3-remote-control/) is an example (it goes in the other direction though - NXT controlling EV3).

Another possibility is to use [Lejos](http://www.lejos.org/) or [MonoBrick](http://www.monobrick.dk/). Both have NXT and EV3 remote control libraries,

Comment: I use C++ instead of Python on ev3dev. How do I use bluetooth there?

Comment: How about this? http://www.yakachu.de/nxt/

Comment: umm, I actually cross-compile and execute C++ right on the device, in ev3dev. it provides TTY for various motors but bluetooth isn't one of them. the link you posted is something completely different